# Change a label as a result of an action listener

Tags: java, swing, jframe, event-listener

```
item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        createbox();
       
        heroname.setText("Name of the hero: " + CharName);  
    }
});
```

This is inside a `JMenuItem`, where if I click it, it creates a `createbox` which is another frame and panel that allows me to input the character name in a text field.

Everything works as expected (`Charname` is a static variable that changes within `createbox` when the user clicks the button "finish" that closes that frame and sets `CharName` to whatever was inside the text field)

BUT how do I make the main frame/panel "sleep" while `createbox()` is doing its thing?

Basically: how can I get a `Thread.sleep(x)` to work so it ONLY updates the label `heroname` once `createbox()` is closed again (only when closing it via `ActionListener` on the finish button of course)

Or, if possible: How do I change the label of another frame with a press of a button?

I cannot change `heroname` within `createbox()` and if I try to make it sleep, the whole program is sleeping and doesn't open the 2nd frame.

Comment: This is exactly the type of situation in which the code should be using a modal (blocking) `JDialog` or a `JOptionPane` (modal by default) rather than `JFrame` to take input.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the instance of other frame at `createbox` frame.

1. finish button Just should hide the `createbox` frame.
2. since you have the instance of other frame, when you click on finish, you can Just call the `changeLabel` method of instance.

This is a solution but maybe you can find a better one.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. 
And I "solved" this issue, by simply reloading the frame with the new labels... but not quite what I wanted.